# Error Adding Excel Hyperlink Dynamically to Shapes

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, hyperlink

The below macro ran successfully until I tried adding hyperlinks to it.
I can't seem to define the Anchor correctly.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
For shapesloop = 1 To 3
Dim shapes As Shape
Set shapes = SilSelection.shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, x, y, 370, 30)


    shapes.Name = "S1"
    
    Set HLShape = SilSelection.shapes("S1")
    
    SilSelection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=HLShape, Address:="", SubAddress:=namesheet.Cells(names, 8), ScreenTip:="Please Click"
```

Here is image of cells i'm using to reference the sheet names:

[image: Sheet Names from Row 4 Column 8]

Image of one of the sheets I want button linked to (A1 could be used as cell to link to if needed)

[image: Page button 1 should be directed to]

Comment: I think the Anchor is fine. It runs if you add `.Address` on the argument `SubAddress:=namesheet.Cells(names, 8)`. As is, the Range Object has no specified property, and is defaulting to its `Value` property. So you're providing the `.Value` of that range instead of its location as the SubAddress.

Comment: I should also mention, to have a range create an address to a different worksheet, you should use the `External` parameter of the `Address` property. e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1").Address(External:=True)` will return "[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1" instead of just "$A$1"

Comment: In addition, 1) you only need one reference to the shape.  Use `Set HShape = SilSelection.shapes.AddShape( ...`  and delete the `Set HLShape = SilSelection.shapes("S1")` line. 2) you are naming _All_ your shapes "S1".  You probably want something like `HShape.Name = "S" & shapesloop`  3) to elaborate on Toddleson comment, if you want to Hyperlink to cells on `namesheet`, use `.Address(External:=True)` as noted.  If those cells contain the thing you want to Hyperlink to, use `.Value2` 4) It's not clear what `names` is meant to be in `namesheet.Cells(names, 8)`  maybe it should be `shapesloop`?

Comment: Thankyou for all your help! 'code' .Address(External:=True) 'code' worked as described and took me to sheet where all the sheet names were stored. As suggested by Chris I want to hyperlink to each sheet name stored in 'code' namesheet.Cells(names, 8) 'code'. I tried using 'code' SubAddress:=namesheet.Cells(names, 8).Value 'code' but came up with error. Names is the starting row (Row 4 in this case) .

Comment: @Coookieeee if`SubAddress:=namesheet.Cells(names, 8).Value` causes an error, then you  the content of those cells are not valid link addresses.  Show us (edit your Q) what's in those cells, and what you expect to link to

Comment: @chrisneilsen oh right. yes I was expecting it to just take the string from these cells as the reference for the hyperlink as they are not hyperlinks themselves. I have added images above which should hopefully show more clearly what i'm trying to do. Is there a way I can have the hyperlink use the cells as a string reference without needing to make each cell a hyperlink?

Comment: If the value in`namesheet.Cells(names, 8)` is just the sheet name, build a valid address, like `SubAddress:="'" & namesheet.Cells(names, 8).Value & "'!A1"`